# Limit CPU usage KSH script

Tags: linux, shell, cpu-usage

I have a KSH crawler script that crawls filesystems on my network, and i would like to limit it to 25% cpu usage, so it does not impact running systems. I am currently using nice but when i run SED, FIND, and some other commands CPU is going above 60% and I dont want that to happen.

I have heard of ulimit, but that is for BASH. Is there a KSH variant of this?

Comment: CPU above 60% probably means the CPU would be 60% idle if the script were not running. Is there actual evidence of other processes being starved of CPU?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick No, but we cannot take any chance that there will be...nor can we take these systems offline, without failing over to DR. Which is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple cores, use CPU-pinning AKA CPU-affinity. See [`taskset`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/taskset.1.html)

> The Linux scheduler  will  honor
>          the  given CPU affinity and the process will not run on any other CPUs.